# iPhone Sdk: How to add a second UINavigationController?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

i created an app from the navigation-based template given by apple. Now i want to add a second navigation controller to my application including a new UITableView. Can anybody show my how to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you want a new navigation controller and not a new view controller?

Comment: Yes, because i want to create a whole new view heirachy.

Comment: Do you want to switch between these navigation controllers with a toolbar or tab bar? Or is the navigation controller supposed to appear in a modal dialog? Or what's the need for the second one?

Comment: at some point in the app i want the second navigation controller to come up from the bottom and inside this second view controller i want to navigate through different tableViews. And i want it to be dismissed with the same animation it appeared with (slide form top to bottom)

Comment: The way i see it, if i just add a regular viewcontroller i got only two options:
either i can push it in and then i always got the connection with the back button to the original navigationController,
Or i do a simple presentModalViewcontroller,  but then i won't be able to navigate through the tableviews using back buttons and the right animations. see where i'm getting at?

Answer (score 1):

I think this can be done. In your app delegate you normally do something like 
`[window addSubview:navController.view]`. UIWindow is just a UIView. So if you create two `UIView` ivars in the `UIViewController` that will contain the two nav controllers you should be able to do a similar thing:

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController
{
  UIView* upperView;
  UIView* lowerView;
}
```

etc...

```
MyUpperRootViewController* myUpperRVC = [[MyUpperRootViewController alloc] init...
UINavigationController* myUpperNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:myUpperRVC];
[upperView addSubview:navController.view];
[myUpperRVC release];
```

and something similar on `lowerView`.

In the root view  or subseqeunt views pushed onto the controllers access them in the usual way as if there was one nav controller. `[self.navigationController push...` should behave normally.

For animating in (and out) the view controllers, just apply the animation to the views - upperView or lowerView. You might want to start with their frames off the visible display and then change them to something visible inside an animation block.